# Run a python file that utilises conda packages with just a double-click on a file. (windows)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, miniconda

I want to run a python file to a windows computer that uses packages installed with miniconda **with one double-click** (*this is very inmportant*).

The computer that I will run it, does not have anything installed (you can think of it as a formatted pc).

I figured out to do it with .bat file and it works, but I have to run the file twice, since the first time after installing miniconda, the shell needs to restart. I searched but I did not find a command to restart the shell and continue with the execution of the python file in order to be done with just one double-click. So, only for the first time, it has to be done manually.

Is there a way to do it with a batch file or should I do it otherwise?

Here is my batch file

```
START %CD%\Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=%CD%\miniconda3
CALL conda activate .\envs_dir
python python_script.py
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the installation changes the user environment variables and not the local environment variables. @Mofi explains it in detain on the comments of my post. I switched my batch file as follows:

```
START %CD%\Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=%CD%\miniconda3
TIMEOUT 40
set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;%CD%\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;%CD%\miniconda3\Library\bin;%CD%\miniconda3\Scripts
CALL conda activate .\envs_dir
python python_script.py
```

**UPDATE**

For a more robust batch script, following the comments of @Mofi, I changed my script to:

```
"%~dp0Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe" /InstallationType=JustMe /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=0 /S /D="%~dp0miniconda3"
set "PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;%~dp0miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;%~dp0miniconda3\Library\bin;%~dp0miniconda3\Scripts"
call "%~dp0miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat" activate "%~dp0envs_dir"
"%~dp0envs_dir\python.exe" "%~dp0python_script.py"
```